# Javamail as JNDI resource in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jndi

We want to send mail from inside my tomcat web application.

I inherited some code from a predecessor that uses a context configuration file inside tomcat to define the data source that I use in my application through a JNDI lookup. This file currently looks like this:

```
<Context path="/chronicle" debug="5" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">

<Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" prefix="ej-Log." suffix=".txt" timestamp="true"/>
<Resource   name="jdbc/chronicle" 
                auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="sa"
            password="xxxxxxxx"
                driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" 
                url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/PsDb"
                maxActive="-1"
                maxIdle="0"
/>
</Context>
```

I have never been able to find documentation for this and never met the guy who did it so I don't really understand it, I simply know that it works.

This morning, it occurred to me that I could use the same tools to configure the mail server. Does anyone know how to do this inside the context configuration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tomcat user guide tells you how to do it:

[Tomcat 7 JNDI How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JavaMail_Sessions)

I didn't check to see if it changed from Tomcat 6 so here's that too:

[Tomcat 6 JNDI How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JavaMail_Sessions)

Answer (score 0):

Where on earth have you looked if you weren't able to find documentation for this? The [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JavaMail_Sessions) has a separate chapter for declaring JNDI resources and in that chapter, there is a section describing how to declare JavaMail sessions.

Comment: I don't know how I failed to find it unless I've always been looking for the context configuration part.